# Linking data in java microservices in a database per service implementation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, microservices, cqrs

I am building a java / spring microservices where each service has it own database . Let's say i have a user service that stores user information in one of the table and a orders service that stores only the username of the person who orders as described below :-

```
User Service (UserService Database - User Table )
id     firstName    lastName     username     age 
1       Chris        Brown       c.brown      20
2       John         Doe         j.doe        25
```

And orders service as below

```
 Order Service (OrderService Database - Order Table )
    id     username    productName     productPrice     OrderDate 
    1      c.brown       Sony Mic       100$            20-08-2018
    2       j.doe       Television      j.doe           11-07-2018
```

Question is what is the best approach to get firstName and lastName from user service while listing the orders . I am aware that microservices should communicate via Rest API , but if i have 1000 users with orders , i will have to loop 1000 times to get the firstName and lastName or take usernames as array , activity which might be expensive .

I have read on using CQRS and event sourcing , but not sure how to best apply it in this scenario .

Comment: If services running on same DB instance you can join by username (make sure field indexed in both tables) or keep some copy of first/last names in orders db, otherwise use any cache to load user first/last names into it.

Comment: Are `Order` and `User` separate microservice?

Comment: @MehrajMalik , yes separate microservice and separate DB

Comment: @GeorgyGobozov , Thanks for the feedback , will consider that approach..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to build a scalable and resilient application your microservices should not make synchronous calls from one to another (you can read `The Art of Scalability` book).

This means that when a microservice receive a request from its clients it should have all the data already gathered in its local storage. In your case, you have two possibilities:

1. add the `firstName`, `lastName` columns to the `Orders table`
2. create another table with users having `id`, `firstName`, `lastName` columns and make a `join` when returning data to the clients.

To keep the replicated information eventually consistent with the source (the Users service) you can use one of the following technics:

1. have a `cron` job that fetches all the needed user information and replaces all the `firstName`, `lastName` columns.
2. use integration events; in CQRS/Event sourcing architectures you already have the Domain events - you can subscribe to those. If you don't have CQRS but a plain architecture, then you can add triggers to your database that pushes low level mutation events (row created/updated/deleted) to the subscribed services. For more options you can read `Migrating to Microservice Databases` book by Edson Yanaga

Answer (score 0):

Order Service can keep a shadow copy of limited user information (first name and last name in your case) in its database (using event sourcing) and can build Order object with limited user information all by itself.

Comment: Hi S.K , Thanks for the useful feedback . let me work on your proposed solution .

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, there should be a `REST` call to get the data from other `MS`.

But if these calls are very expensive you should consider changing the DB design and put this required data at a commonplace.